# angular2 upgrade to rc1 "Ruler, Rectangle and Browser" are missing

Tags: angular, upgrade

After upgrading from beta to RC1 typescript compiler throws error on these two lines:

```
import {Ruler, Rectangle} from "angular2/src/platform/browser/ruler";
import * as browser from "angular2/platform/browser";
```

Where did they go?, Were replaced in other package or migrated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RC1 changed the imports to be under the @angular scope, so you'll need to your imports to use `@angular/platform-browser`:

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-rc0-2016-05-02

Comment: I can't find the Ruler at all anymore in RC1. I've searched the complete source code, it's just gone.

Comment: This appears to be a known issue in RC-1:

"Ruler service is not being reexported via @angular/platform-browser"

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/8452#issuecomment-220460761

> mhevery commented 12 days ago
We have decided to remove Ruler service, and so it is not part of the public API.